# Contravariance/Covariance - cannot convert class to interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have the following code

```
public interface IInterface
{
}
public class GenericClass<TSomeClass>
    where TSomeClass : class
{
    public TSomeClass SomeMethod(TSomeClass someClass = null)
    {
        return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance;                   //ERROR:Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeClass' to 'TSomeClass'
        return (TSomeClass)SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance;       //ERROR:Cannot convert type 'SomeClass' to 'TSomeClass'
        return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance as TSomeClass;     //Works when "where TSomeClass : class" clause added
    }
}
public class SomeClass : IInterface
{
    public static SomeClass SomeClassStaticInstance = new SomeClass();
}
```

It generates the compile time errors noted in the comments on the appropriate lines.

I would like to know why I can't just use the first line that generates an error? `SomeClass` implements `IInterface` but I have to mess around with the `as` keyword.

I've tried changing `GenericClass<TSomeClass>` to `GenericClass<out TSomeClass>` but then I get another compile time error `Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant.` which persists, even if i remove the `where TSomeClass : class` clause.

What am I missing ... it obviously works because I can 'force it to' using the `where TSomeClass : class` clause and the `return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance as TSomeClass;` statement!

I do actually need the `where TSomeClass : class` otherwise I get yet another compile time error with `TSomeClass someClass = null` ... `A value of type '<null>' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'TSomeClass'`.

So it's basically compile time errors all the way down! Thanks.

Comment: `where TSomeClass : class` restricts `TSomeClass` to reference objects only, otherwise it can be any type (like value one), and you can't use `null` defaut value, it's better to use `TSomeClass someClass = default(TSomeClass)`

Comment: If `SomeMethod` returns `IInterface` and you add the `IInterface` to `GenericClass`'s generics constraints the first line works.
Not sure if that's what you're looking for though as your question is not very clear to me

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski @nalka Thanks, I used `default` and added the interface to the constraints. @selvin - thanks (though not sure what you mean about SomeMethod being generic, the class is generic, not the method?), also this is a minimal example of what was causing me grief, I'm sorry I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: So if I use `GenericClass<string>`, what should happen then?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your only constraint is that `TSomeClass` is a class, so if you were to instantiate `GenericClass` with a type that isn't `SomeClass`, or a type that derives from it, `return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance;` clearly isn't going to work.

For example:

```
var genericClass = new GenericClass<SomeRandomClass>(); // fine
var randomClass = genericClass.SomeMethod(new SomeRandomClass()); // not fine, a SomeClass is returned!
```

I'm not sure where `IInterface` currently fits into all this?

Maybe you want SomeMethod to return an object that implements `IInterface`; if so, you need to further constrain your generic type, and have your method return an `IInterface`:

```
public class GenericClass<TSomeClass> where TSomeClass : class, IInterface
{
    public IInterface SomeMethod(TSomeClass someClass = null)
    {
        return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance; //This now compiles!
    }
}
```

As for why `return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance as TSomeClass;` worked originally, this was merely a coincidence.

`as` is a safe cast operator, which returns `null` if the attempted cast fails. As you constrained `TSomeClass` to be a class, a `null` return value would be valid. You would always return `null` however, if the generic type you specified wasn't `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

`I would like to know why I can't just use the first line that generates an error? SomeClass implements IInterface but I have to mess around with the as keyword.`

You have to use `(TSomeClass)YourInstance` cast as language is designed to prevent any assumptions on casting generic arguments. [Read more](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/07/10/when-is-a-cast-not-a-cast/).

Because the implicit conversion on type of argument TSomeClass can not be predicted unless you put a constraint of less inherited type e.g. interface. You should change your constraint to `where TSomeClass : IInterface` for variance.

Using `as` key worked because it will return null if the type is incompatible, which is why you need `class` constraint. After changing your constraint to interface the `as` statement will become invalid.

In your factory method you should return `IInterface` so the generic type argument can accept a direct cast.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this would work:

```
public interface IInterface
{
}

public class GenericClass<TSomeClass>
    where TSomeClass : IInterface
{
    //Not sure what the input parameter is for?
    public IInterface SomeMethod(TSomeClass someClass = null)
    {
        return SomeClass.SomeClassStaticInstance;                  
    }
}

public class SomeClass : IInterface
{
    public static IInterface SomeClassStaticInstance = new SomeClass();
}
```

However as noted by others, the question here is really what generics are being used for in this instance - is there possibly a better choice of how to structure your code?

Very hard to tell what the purpose of this would be from the structure you have given us.